# Using Flask's "after_request" handler to get tracebacks of errors

Tags: python, flask

The documentation for [`after_request`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#flask.Flask.after_request) says "As of Flask 0.7 this function might not be executed at the end of the request in case an unhandled exception occurred."  Is there a way to change this so `after_request` functions are called even for unhandled exceptions, for example to log the traceback?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`teardown_request`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#flask.Flask.teardown_request) instead.

> Register a function to be run at the end of each request, regardless of whether there was an exception or not.
>
> These functions are not allowed to modify the request, and their return values are ignored. If an exception occurred while processing the request, it gets passed to each teardown_request function.

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)
# unhandled teardown won't happen while in debug mode
# app.debug = True
# set this if you need the full traceback, not just the exception
# app.config['PROPAGATE_EXCEPTIONS'] = True

@app.route('/')
def index():
    print(test)

@app.teardown_request
def log_unhandled(e):
    if e is not None:
        print(repr(e))
        # app.logger.exception(e)  # only works with PROPAGATE_EXCEPTIONS

app.run('localhost')
```

Note that by the time `teardown_request` is called, the traceback has already fallen out of scope; only the exception is available.  You can change this by setting `PROPAGATE_EXCEPTIONS = True`, although this may have performance issues.  Given that the traceback is logged by Flask already, it may be easier to configure logging rather than trying to log it yourself.